# Alter Dativ "Schwanen"

Tags: grammatical-case

Ich sah heute eine Gaststätte mit dem Namen "Zum Schwanen". Das Wort *Schwanen* dürfte eine alte Dativ-Form von *Schwan* sein. Diese Dativ-Bildung von *Schwan* wird mittlerweile nicht mehr benutzt, man sagt "dem Schwan" bzw. "Zum Schwan".

Für mich gilt als Faustregel, dass der Dativ eines Substantivs mit seinem Nominativ übereinstimmt, d.h. keine  Deklinationsendung benutzt wird. Dennoch hat sich die alte Dativ-Form mit Deklinationsendung "-en" bzw. "-n" in einigen Fällen erhalten. Beispiele:

- dem Elefanten
- dem Löwen
- dem Hasen
- dem Bauern
- dem Ochsen

Meine Fragen:

**Wurde der Dativ früher generell mit Deklinationsendung "-en" bzw. "-n" gebildet? Seit wann wurde die Deklinationsendung weggelassen?**

**Gibt es eine Regel, für welche Worte die alte Dativ-Bildung weiter verwendet wird - oder ist es rein zufällig?**

Comment: "warum" ist bei Sprache eine Frage, die meistens nicht beantwortet werden kann. Sprache wird ja nicht gemacht und beschlossen, also gibt auch keiner einen Grund an.

Comment: Siehe auch https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1625/what-is-the-problem-with-why-questions-and-how-to-deal-with-them

Comment: Würde eine sprachgeschichtliche Darstellung, wann diese Form verschwunden ist, deine Frage beantworten? Würde eine Systematik - eine grammatische Regularität, welche Worte in der einen Form dekliniert werden, und welche in der anderen - deine Frage beantworten?

Comment: Nur der *Elefant* aus der ersten Liste taugt als Beispiel, denn *Löwe* und *Hase* bringen das *e* ja schon mit.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Primär eine sprachgeschichtliche Darstellung. Vielleicht ergibt sich daraus auch eine Regel, welche Worte in welcher Weise dekliniert werden.

Comment: @guidot Trotzdem könnte es auch "dem Löwe" oder "dem Hase" heißen.

Comment: @KritikerderElche: Das ist richtig, aber eine so viel generellere Frage ("Warum weisen in manchen Deklinationen und Fällen angehängte Buchstaben auf den Fall hin?"), dass ich nicht sehe, wie das Deiner Frage hilft.

Comment: @KritikerderElche: https://german.stackexchange.com/editing-help shows some background information for editing  (can be reached via question mark icon on the upper right during editing).  I would probably insert rulers or try boldface instead.

Comment: @KritikerderElche Bitte ändere / ergänze deine Frage entsprechend, sodass klarer erkennbar ist, welche Art von Antwort du erwartest, welche Art von Antwort dein Bedürfnis befriedigen würde. Das ist ein teil der Frage und sollte nicht im Kommentar bleiben. Und: Ich habe die Frage fett formattiert, das ist eine Möglichkeit der Hervorhebung, anstelle der Zitat-Markierung.

Comment: Keine Antwort auf die Frage, nur ein Denkanstoß: Ähnlich ist es auch bei _dem Automat(en)_ und auch im Akkusativ bei _niemand(en)_, _jemand(en)_. Mir scheint, da erleben wir gerade, wie die Kasusendung nach und nach abgeschliffen wird.

Comment: Mir schwant, der Dativ von "Schwan" wird so oder so mit -n gebildet.

Answer (score 5):

Dies ist nur eine der lustigen Eigenschaften der deutschen Sprache. Einige maskuline Substantive, so genannte schwache Substantive, haben im Dativ und Akkusativ ein -n angehängt. Sie beziehen sich in der Regel auf Menschen und große Tiere. Auch Substantive, die auf "-e" enden, sind oft schwach. Historisch gesehen wurden die Wörter in den Vorfahren des Deutschen viel flektiert. Dies hat im Laufe der Zeit abgenommen, aber bei einigen Wörtern schneller als bei anderen. Daher gibt es Wörter, die andere Beugungsmuster haben als andere. Ähnlich dekliniert man manche Verben mit Ablauten und manche nicht. Zum Beispiel: "Er sieht" aus "sehen", aber "Er steht" aus "stehen".

Bitte entschuldigen Sie mein gebrochenes Deutsch. Ich bin auch ein Lerner.

Comment: Danke für die Antwort! Und gebrochenes Deutsch sehe ich hier nicht.

Comment: Das einzige gebrochen Deutsch, das hier entdecken konnte, wäre "Lerner". Die Entschuldigung erscheint dahingehend unnötig. (gängiger wäre wohl "lernender", jedoch ebenfalls unüblich).