# in diesem Falle und Falle

Tags: meaning, vocabulary, declension

Ich habe eine Frage. Warum bedeutet (**in diesem Falle**) ([**in that case**](https://www.dict.cc/?s=in%20diesem%20Falle)), obwohl nur (**Falle**) ([**Trick zu täuschen**](https://en.langenscheidt.com/german-english/falle)) definiert wird? ich habe darüber gedacht, dass vielleicht es (**Fall**) ist, aber ich bemerkte, dass plural von Fall (**Fälle**)ist. Daher hat (**falle**) nicht zu tun hat mit (**fall**).

**langenscheidt**:
Fạl•le die; -, -n

1. eine Konstruktion, mit der man Tiere fängt <eine Falle aufstellen, Fallen stellen, legen>: Die Maus ist in die Falle gegangen
   || -K: Kaninchenfalle, Mausefalle
2. jemandem eine Falle stellen;
   jemanden in eine Falle locken einen Trick anwenden, um jemanden zu täuschen und ihm zu schaden: Der Prüfer hat mir mit seiner Frage eine Falle gestellt, und ich bin darauf hereingefallen
3. gespr hum ≈ Bett

Comment: Du warst auf dem richtigen Weg, hier hättest Du alle Formen von „Fall“ nachschlagen können: https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Fall

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Deklination von "der Fall" im Singular:
Der Fall
des Fall(e)s
dem Fall(e)
den Fall

d.h. "Falle" ist auch eine (etwas veraltete und zunehmend weniger genutzte) Form des Dativs Singular von "Fall".

Im allgemeinen findet man - gerade in feststehenden Begriffen - noch häufig den Dativ mit der e-Endung.

Siehe auch [diesen Artikel](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/fragen/25) für eine längere Bemerkung zum Dativ-e.

In diesem Falle könnte man auch "in diesem Fall" sagen ohne, dass die Bedeutung und die Verständlichkeit sich änderte.

In meiner persönlichen Sprachpraxis ist "in diesem Fall" die übliche Form, außer ich äußerte mich etwas nachdenklich wie "in diesem Falle... hm... tun wir XY" - dann könnte ich ggf. das Dativ-e gebrauche (aber auch nicht immer). Die Nutzung hat eher etwas mit der Sprach- bzw. Satzmelodie denn mit grammatikalischen Überlegungen zu tun.

Comment: Einen ähnlichen Fall mit zwei Dativformen, von denen eine zunehmend veraltet, hatten wir hier: [Alter Dativ "Schwanen"](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/67940/alter-dativ-schwanen)

Comment: Siehe auch diese [Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/17381/1696)